# LIKE to select only the exact keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

Is it possible to SELECT LIKE the exact word in comma-separated column?

tags: php,web,webdevelopment,java,javascript

```
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE "%java%"'
```

This will select "java" and "javascript"

Is it possible to select ONLY "java"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for that

```
select * from your_table
where find_in_set('java', tags) > 0
```

#### But actually you should rather change your table definition. Never store multiple values in a single column.

A better DB design would be

```
posts table
-----------
id
title
body
...


tags table
----------
id
name
...


post_tags table
---------------
post_id
tag_id
```

Then you could query posts having the `java` tag like this

```
select p.*
from posts p
join post_tags pt on pt.post_id = p.id
join tags t on pt.tag_id = t.id
where t.name = 'java'
```

That is much cleaner, easier and also very fast.

Comment: But here I can't every tag in one own row, they must be stored in the same row with other details of the post

Answer (score 1):

MySql supports [regular expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html), regular expressions support word boundaries:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]java[[:>:]]';
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should store tags in a junction table, with one row per whatever and per tag.  This is the right way to store lists in SQL.

Another answer shows how to use `find_in_set()`.  If you are keen on using `like`, you can do:

```
WHERE CONCAT(',', tags, ',') LIKE "%,java,%"'
```

Although the performance should be similar to `find_in_set()` in MySQL, the only advantage to this method is that it will work in more databases.  Let me repeat, though, that the right thing to do is fix the data structure to have a junction table rather than storing lists in a string column.

Answer (score 1):

1NF: The domain of each attribute contains only atomic values.
Redesign your table to support 1NF.
EDIT: What do you think happens when you want to update the column? Or you want to remove java from the table? It is much easier to access, delete and update rows when they follow normalization rules.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer given before me is good but i had another solution that i felt to share.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags  LIKE "java" OR tags   LIKE "%,java," OR tags   LIKE "java,%"
```

Which simply means that there can be 4 conditions in the column:

tags   column has only java in it 
tags   column may have ,java, in it
tags   column has only java, in it

Useful link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

I hope this helps you.

Comment: `LIKE "%,java%"` matches also ",javascript".

Comment: @GrzegorzGierlik, thanks for notifying edited. One up vote for you :) for your comment.